# Error Unresolved reference: android. problem with plugins

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i recently installed android studio and i had no problem with it, suddenly this error shown up and i have no idea what is it
this problem is related to build.gradle.kts (Module App)
at first i got another error with this title "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:"

this is the entire build.gradle.kts (Module App) code:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20" apply false
}


android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

then i added these 3 codes in plugins:

```
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20" apply false
```

then i recieved this error: "e: file:///C:/Users/EXO/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle.kts:8:1: Unresolved reference: android" which related to android method in line 8

Answer (score 1):

2 Things:

1. you shouldn't use `apply false` in the app gradle file.
2. you can't apply both `android.library` and `android.application` in the same module.